# Unable to create an operator== for a generic type?

Tags: generics, c++-cli, operator-overloading

I've got a generic range class and I'm trying to add a comparison operator so I can test whether one range is equal to another. It fails to compile and I'm not sure how to fix the issues it's complaining about. Have I missed something obvious? Here's a snippet of the code:

```
generic<typename T>
public ref class Range
{
protected:
    T m_min;
    T m_max;
public:

    ...
    ...

    bool operator==(Range<T>% rhs) 
    {
        return ( m_min == rhs.m_min ) && ( m_max == rhs.m_max );
    }
};
```

...which fails to compile with the following error:

```
1>c:\projects\Utils.h(47) : error C2676: binary '==' : 'T' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

Do I need to define conversions for each type that I want to overload (I'm using an Int32 instantiation)? I was hoping to avoid that sort of thing as it rather detracts from using generics.

**[Edit]** I've got an instantiation as follows:

```
Range<Int32> a = Range<Int32>(0,5);
Range<Int32> b = Range<Int32>(1,3);

if( Int32(2) != Int32(4) )
{
    printf("Int32 supports != operator");
}

if( a != b )
{
    printf("A != B : SUCCESS");
}
else
{
    printf("A == B : FAIL");
}
```

...which compiles okay aside fromt he aforementioned errors. If I convert each value to an Int32 it compiles, but really I'd like to keep the class as generic as possible (i.e. not havnig to overload for each and every type). I guess I could subclass for each type and do the overloaded operators there, but the solution is less neat than I had expected when I first discovered `generic`s ;-)

Comment: You have an instantiation of that class where T is replace with an actual type - does that type has a == operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare values of a generic type with an == operator because not all value types are guaranteed to implement it.

For example, this code sample fails with error "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Test.MyStruct' and 'Test.MyStruct'.

```
struct MyStruct { }

class Tester {
    void Go()
    {
        bool b = new MyStruct() == new MyStruct();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In standard C++ you would write

```
template< class T >
class Range {

    bool operator==(Range const & rhs) const {
        return ( m_min == rhs.m_min ) && ( m_max == rhs.m_max );
    }
};
```

and it would work as long as the type T has an operator==

But this is obviously not standard C++, the `generic`, thing the `public ref class`, the `Range<T>%`

Look for some special rules regarding `generic` things, I would guess they put more constrains on the type T than a standard template.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was hoping to do, but it seems generics are more restricted than I'd hoped (or I've not found the appropriate way of achieving the same thing).

Answer (score 1):

In VS2005 at least, what's needed is:

```
generic<typename T> where T: IComparable, IEquatable<T>
public ref class Range {
    ...
};
```

This leads to the compiler accepting the == operator. I didn't test the Range class, but it works as it should for the following static method of a class:

```
generic <class K, class V> where V: IComparable, IEquatable<V>
static
K
KeyForValue(Collections::Generic::IDictionary<K,V>^ src, V value) {
    for each (Collections::Generic::KeyValuePair<K,V>^ kvp in src) {
        if (kvp->Value==value) return kvp->Key ;
    }
    throw gcnew Collections::Generic::KeyNotFoundException() ;
    return K() ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can use "Range" instead of "Range<T>" when T is the same type as the type the class template is instantiated with. Give that a try.

Off-topic, but I'd return a const bool, and make that function const too. Also change protected to private unless you know you need protected.

And I assume that '%' is a typo for '&'? EDIT: except I just noticed the c++-cli tag, so that's probably some crazy operator present in C++/CLI, which sadly I know nothing about :)

Comment: Fair points on the const's and private. Yes you're right about the C++/CLI craziness ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `where IComparable` constraint?

```
generic<typename T> where T: IComparable
public ref class Range  {
....
```